# Fluid construction of parallel promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

My question is about the elegant parallelization of promises in [BlueBird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) when you need to pass both the context and argument to the functions building the promises.

To make my problem understandable and testable, I made an example with no dependency.

Let's suppose I do computation ( 1/(x*x*x) + 1/(x*x) ) involving an asynchronous "computer" (whose resources must be released). The square and the cube are computed asynchronously and independently.

I can do my computation like this :

```
InitComputer(2) // returns a promise
.then(invert)
.then(function(arg){
    return Promise.all([
        proto.square(arg),
        proto.cube(arg)
    ]);
}).spread(function(sq, cu){
    this.set(sq + cu);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err:', err);
}).finally(endComputer);
```

But I find this usage of `all` too heavy compared to what is theoretically possible. When you pass a function as argument to `then`, it's executed. When you pass functions to `all`, they're not, there's an error. I suspect I'm missing a utility or pattern...

Is there a solution to change it to something simpler in this style :

```
InitComputer(2)
.then(invert)
.all([
    proto.square,
    proto.cube
]).spread(function(sq, cu){
    this.set(sq + cu);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err:', err);
}).finally(endComputer);
```

?

I could probably hack [Promise.prototype.all](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promise.js#L198) or define a new function to avoid increasing the polymorphism but I'm only interested in solutions not involving the modification of objects I don't own.

---

**Annex:**

Here's how is defined the "computer" for my test :

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

function Computer(){}
function InitComputer(v){
    // initializing a computer is asynchronous and may fail hence the promise
    var c = new Computer(), resolver = Promise.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (v>1) resolver.resolve(v);
        else resolver.reject(new Error("bad value: "+v));
    },100);
    return resolver.promise.bind(c);
}
var proto = Computer.prototype;
proto.square = function(x){
    // imagine this really uses the computer and is asynchronous
    if (!this instanceof Computer) throw new Error('not a computer');
    return x*x
}
proto.cube = function(x){ return x*x*x }
proto.set = function(v){ this.value = v }

function endComputer(){
    // releases resources here
    console.log('value:', this.value);
}

// this asynchronous function doesn't involve or know the computer
function invert(v){ return 1/v }
```

Comment: I might be getting something wrong, but aren't `proto.square(arg)` and `proto.cube(arg)` evaluated immediately, before passing their results to the array constructor for `Promise.all`? (edit) oh, ok, they are probably supposed to be async, never mind.

Comment: @Groo Exactly. *"imagine this really uses the computer and is asynchronous"*. I made the minimal code to let the question readable, so I had to take some shortcuts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `Promise.all` there. Instead of doing:

```
.then(function(arg){
    return Promise.all([
        proto.square(arg),
        proto.cube(arg)
    ]);
}).spread(...
```

You can simply use:

```
.then(function(arg){
    return [proto.square(arg), proto.cube(arg)];
}).spread(...
```

If we had arrow functions in node.js, it'd be as simple as:

```
.then(arg => [proto.square(arg), proto.cube(arg)]).spread(...
```

`Promise.all` is to be used when you need to *start* a chain of promises with at least 2 promises. For example:

```
var promise1 = somePromise();
var promise2 = somePromise2();

// Start the chain here
Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
.spread(function(value1, value2) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It's not really as simple as I hoped but it's really acceptable.

Comment: I wonder why `all`, contrary to `then`, doesn't execute functions in argument.

Comment: @dystroy hah, it was mostly about using `this.square` and `this.cube` though.

Answer (score 1):

For management of resources use case like you are mentioning, bluebird has [`Promise.using()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promiseusingpromisedisposer-promise-promisedisposer-promise--function-handler---promise).  `Promise.using()` lets you setup [`disposer()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#disposerfunction-disposer---disposer) function for automatically closing the asynchronously-retrieved resource when you done using

[`Promise.join()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise) would help as well to combine the results of the `cube` and `square` async methods

Here I slightly re-wrote your `InitComputer` example to illustrate how this works - it now returns the `Computer` instance with val added as a property, instead of the val, and I placed `endComputer` on the proto also

note: you can always use `Promise.method()` like so instead of returning a deferred:

`var invert = Promise.method(function invert(v){ return 1/v })`

**new initComputer:**

```
function InitComputer(v){
    var c = new Computer(), resolver = Promise.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (v>1) {
            c.val = v;
            resolver.resolve(c);
        }
        else resolver.reject(new Error("bad value: "+v));
    },100); /** notice resource disposer function added below **/
    return resolver.promise.bind(c).disposer(function(compu){compu.endComputer()});
}
```

**new code:**

```
Promise.using(InitComputer(1.2), function(computer){
    return invert(computer.val)
    .then(function(inverted){
        return Promise.join(computer.square(inverted), computer.cube(inverted), 
            function(sq, cu){
                computer.set(sq + cu)
            }
        )
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('err:', err);
    });
})
```

Comment: +1 but you're answering an old already answered question with functions (like `Promise.using`) which weren't available at the time of asking. It's a little messy to revive this old question. Note that `Promise.defer()` is now declared by the author of BlueBird to be an antipattern as he prefers the simpler `new Promise(f1,f2)`.

Comment: Thanks yea coming in late but this came up 1st in my search so figured I would ad $0.02.. I also found answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615891/best-practice-to-hang-on-to-variables-when-using-promises) which much helpful in this topic also